# Phrase to help count 3 groups of 17?

Tags: rhythm

I'm trying to learn to count 3 groups of 17.

For example, for 2 groups of 11, I came up with:

```
1-ap-ple-a-day-keeps-the-doc-tor-a-way  
2-ap-ple(s)-a-day-keep-the-doc-tor-a-way
```

What's something similar that I can use for 3 groups of 17? Like:

```
1-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da
2-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da
3-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da-da-Da
```

Thanks.

Comment: In each grouping of 17, which beats are emphasized?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I figure that out?

Comment: If you're looking at/listening to an actual piece of music, you can inspect where beams are broken in the sheet music, evaluate which beats the drum beat emphasizes, determine the beats on which new phrases begin, or look for rhythmic patterns that imply a particular structure of strong and weak beats.

Comment: normally, unusual counts like 7, 10, 11, etc will be broken up into groups of 2 and 3

Comment: sorry, I missed your Da da breakdown of stresses

Comment: The first example is actually 2 bars of 5/4, so the whole question seems tro be asked under a false premise.

Comment: I'm going cross eyed reading the 'Da-da's I see 3 lines, exact same pattern of 16+1. I'm assuming the "1" "2" "3" starting each line is meant to be the starting downbeat and would be the same as the capital "Da"

Comment: Could yo tell us in what purpose you are searching this? The answers might be different if you mean to compose music or write lyrics in such rythm, or if you have  to make a metrical index of tunes, for instance

Comment: When using words to show beats, it's best to use *one syllable per beat*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at poetry written in a 17-syllable meter, for instance:

```
1    2   3     4  5   6    7  8    9    10 11 12     13  14  15    16  17
Thís is the | fórest pri | méval, the | múrmuring | píne and the | hémlocks
```

- (Introduction to *Evangeline: A Tale of Acadie* Henry Wadsworth
  Longfellow, 1807 - 1882)

Then for a 1,2,3 pattern, craft your 5 Dactyls (triplets) and the final Trochee (duplet).

```
1 pretty kitty   eats meat in the morning along with some salmon.
2 pretty kitties eat  meat in the morning along with some salmon.
3 pretty kitties eat  meat in the morning along with some salmon.
```

Comment: Would "1 pretty kitty eats meat in the morning along with spaghetti..." work too?

Comment: Yes, works just the same, although my cat doesn't particularly like spaghetti.  He is quite fond of the Friskies' chicken and salmon shreds.

Answer (score 4):

If this feels like 4/4 time with an extra beat tagged on at the end, then I would count each measure as:

```
1-ee-and-uh-2-ee-and-uh-3-ee-and-uh-4-ee-and-uh-5`
```

If you want the pattern to count up and don't need to worry about accenting a particular beat, I would recommend this:

```
1-ee-and-uh-IS-ee-and-uh-SEV-ee-and-uh-EN-ee-and-uh-TEEN`
2-ee-and-uh-IS-ee-and-uh-SEV-ee-and-uh-EN-ee-and-uh-TEEN`
3-ee-and-uh-IS-ee-and-uh-SEV-ee-and-uh-EN-ee-and-uh-TEEN`
```

Then, internalize the "ee-and-uh"s so that you don't have to count them out loud. This leaves you with:

```
1 / / / IS / / / SEV / / / EN / / / TEEN`
2 / / / IS / / / SEV / / / EN / / / TEEN`
3 / / / IS / / / SEV / / / EN / / / TEEN`
```

If you were to learn this method, it would be easier because you'll only have to count 5 beats, and the rest you will be able to simply feel intuitively.

Another value of this pattern is that, if you are learning to count/feel lots of different odd meters, then you can easily remember which one is 17/8 versus, e.g., 15/8.

If you want the 17 beats in groupings of 3 (so that every third beat is a strong beat), then you could use:

```
1-and-uh-THIS-and-uh-IS-and-uh-SEV-and-uh-EN-and-uh-TEEN-OH
2-and-uh-THIS-and-uh-IS-and-uh-SEV-and-uh-EN-and-uh-TEEN-OH
3-and-uh-THIS-and-uh-IS-and-uh-SEV-and-uh-EN-and-uh-TEEN-OH
```

Once you internalize the weak beats (the "and-uh"s), you can count it more easily like this:

```
1 / / THIS / / IS / / SEV / / EN / / TEEN OH
2 / / THIS / / IS / / SEV / / EN / / TEEN OH
3 / / THIS / / IS / / SEV / / EN / / TEEN OH
```

Answer (score 2):

What is some-thing sim-il-ar that would fit for three groups of sev-en-teen.

Comment: Wow, synchronicity much?

Comment: I figured why not try it.  I am sure you'll get better answers but I couldn't resist.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming captial 'Da' is the stress. It's duple and 16+1.

But, a meter like 17/8 seems to obscure the very regular stress given except for the last group.

It seems a mix of 2/4 and 5/8 meters makes the clearest break down of beats and stresses.

```
2/4 1 + 2 + | 1 + 2 + | 1 + 2 + | 5/8 1 + 2 + a
```

I'm seeing this as a subdivision of 2 rather than 4. So instead of treating 'Da-da-Da-da' as `1 e & a` I reduce that to just `Da-da` twice which counts as `1 + 2 +`. If you had written something like `Da-da-ti-da` or otherwise differentiated the 1st and 3rd events, then a subdivision of 4 would have been appropriate.

I don't see how the various mnemonics suggested in other answers are supposed to help.

If it's put into meters that reflect your stress pattern, it's not overly complicated, and a mnemonic becomes necessary. Personally, I feel the mnemonic seems to obscure the pattern.

If a mnemonic is really desired, wouldn't it make sense to pick parts of speech to reflect the beat divisions?...

```
up and down and
left and right and
in and out and
there and back a-gain
```

... that a pattern of 4 + 4 + 4 + 5 = 17 eighth notes.

Answer (score 2):

Sheet music and notes would make the question more clear

Using 4 times **Da-ba-da-ra** with a final **Da** and counting with the fingers of the left hand instead of **1**234 - **2**234 - **3**234  **4**234  **5**!) and the right hand counts the lines would make it easy to get along : 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 1=17

1) **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**

2) **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**

3) **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**-ba-da-ra + **Da**

In jazz counting 8th notes goes Da-ba-Da-ba 
(where the -ba is creating a swing as the da is longer than the ba.) 
Thus you might also use this by counting 4 times **Da-ba-Da-ba**  with a final **Da**! for each line.

Comment: Is "Da-ba-da-ra" a common Swiss method for counting sixteenth-note subdivisions?

Comment: No, I just "invented" it. But  I meant Da-ba-Ra-ba, of course , this makes more sense. It' s the way I use to practise chains of groups of 16th notes (ehe variations of an euphonium solo e.g. ot o, I just "invented" it. But  I meant Da-ba-Ra-ba, of course , this makes more sense. It' s the way I use to practise chains of groups of 16th notes (e.g.the variations of an euphonium solo, invention nr.8 or the violin concerto of bach).

Comment: . But there is actually a smart method in a swiss school music book that goes likes this: ta - ta - ta -ta = 4 fourth notes ta - te - ta - ta - te .... for 4 eighth notes and ta-ge-te-ge for 4 sixteenth notes.

Comment: I see. I'd never heard of it before, so I just wondered if it was a European thing. Just curious!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand where you want to put the accents.  If it does not matter then I think that I would break down 17 into a nine plus an eight and then further break down the nine to three sets of three and the eight to four sets of two.

So my result would be

Da da da  Da da da  Da da da  Da da  Da da  Da da  Da da

or if counting

1 2 3 |2 2 3 |3 2 3 |1 2 |2 2 |3 2 |4 2

For me this is easier to count in my head or to say out loud.

Answer (score 1):

Using [konnakol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konnakol) (you can find [many](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lkf16wFnPaQ) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlY7rp9xm0I) on it):

```
|| ta ka ta ki ṭa | ta ka ta ki ṭa | ta ka ta ki ṭa | taam  . ||
|| ta ka ta ki ṭa | ta ka ta ki ṭa | ta ka ta ki ṭa | tohm  . ||
|| ta ka ta ki ṭa | ta ka ta ki ṭa | ta ka ta ki ṭa | dheem . ||
```

Quick note: The 't' is dental (close enough to the Spanish/French denti-alveolar 't') and 'ṭ' is retroflex (but can be approximated by alveolar 't' of English).

The period (.) indicates a rest (of unit duration)

Here the difference in the three phrases is at the *end*, but it could easily be moved to the start.