# thirteen within 4 beats?

Tags: practice, rhythm, tuplet

How would you go about executing the rhythm pattern in bar 15 of Frank Zappa's "The Black Page #2"?

[image: "The Black Page #2" mm. 13 – 17]

"The Page" is in 4/4 time; how does one practice making 13 regular strokes within 4 beats? Executing thirteen (or 11, or 7, or 5) regular strokes in one beat is quite easy, but distributing these 13 strokes over 4 beats, I can't imagine how to do it properly.

Here is a link to the source of the above image:

https://musescore.com/user/23884321/scores/6550554

Comment: The same learning technique is discussed in [How can I count 17 against 3 polyrhythm?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/78667/70803).

Comment: Yes, absolutly it does, thank you. So in my case, starting from 13 against 1 which is easy, I should count and have a stroke on just one count every four to get a 13 against 4 rhythm pattern. In therry it sounds good, but in practice not so easy... I wonder if a best way of executing 13 against 4 would not be the following : start from the easier 13 against 1, and just do it 4 times slower by "feeling". I think this could be achieved by practising thousands of times the following :

Comment: start from a simple rhythmic pattern in a given tempo, and execute the same pattern twice as fast, 4 times faster and twice as slow, 4 times slower, within the same basic pulse. Then go for the same with more and more complex rythmic patterns thousands of times, in order to aqcuire the "intuitive sense" of executing the same pattern twice or 4 times faster and slower. Once this "feeling" is automatised in the brain, it should be applied easily to execute "intuitively" 13 against 2 or 13 against 4, starting from 13 against 1, without having to make those horrible countings.

Comment: You can subdivide 1 into 13 *easily*? I sure can't. I would approach this as "Well, if this were 12 notes, they'd just be triplets. In fact, I was just playing triplets before this. So just go 'a tiny bit faster.'" I might even intentionally practice three groups of triplets plus one of sixteenths, then try to "equalize" the groups more. I would *not* focus on being aware of the polyrhythmic interplay of these notes with the four beats of the measure; i.e. I wouldn't focus on [anything] **against** [anything], just on [something] **within** [something].

Comment: @Andy : playing a bit faster than 4 triplets and adding 1 in the end is a very good aproach indeed ! I think it is the best approach so far. No exotic and complex countings, just 3 + 3 + 3 + 4, along with an intuitive sense of "equalizing" which is achievable with a bit of practice. Moreover this is applicable for other kinds of tuplets. Very elegant !

Comment: I should add, this being Zappa, complex and funky math is part of the point, but if this were, say Chopin, I would say it *shouldn't* be 13 equal notes, and we would schmear the values all around expressively.

Comment: @Andy : dividing 1 into 13 is easy, count for example 3 + 3 + 3 + 4 as above, and try to equalize the strokes. Same for 7 (4 + 3), 9 (3+3+3), 10 (5+5), 11 (4+4+3) and so on so forth... clearly the longer the tuplet, the harder to do it at high tempi.. but the general principle is easy and very intuitive.

Comment: @Andy : yes, I think one of the aspects of that piece is a game  Zappa played between 11 -12 -13, since other bars are displaying 11 within 4, and other regular triplets (3x4=12).

Answer (score 1):

You say you can execute 13 regular strokes within 1 beat quite easily. Thus, try treating all 4 beats of the usual measure as 1 giant mega-beat instead, and then execute all 13 strokes within that. (Spacing out all 13 strokes properly within that one slow mega-beat might be a little intimidating.)

Comment: Yes you're right, but two problems I see with that way of doing : first, that "mega beat" is at very slow tempo, and the slower the tempo, the more difficult to execute accurately a tuple. And second, if the drummer go on marking the basic pulse, you will be easily disturbed executing this 13-uplet, since 13 is a prime number and therefore none of the notes of the tuplet will correspond with any of the intermediate pulses done by the drummer. So I think that is not so easy as you say unfortunately.

Comment: @huurd - My natural instinct just now was still to mega-beat the 13-tuplet just now, except with 2 underlying mega-beats instead of 1. I still think the mega-beat is one of the best strategies for this if you want a competent version of the tuplet fast.

Comment: And I guess by the time I was done writing my comment I realized that Dekkadeci pretty much says the same thing. So yeah, I'd use some of my suggestions as initial "crutches" to help you get to this point: Start by subdividing "wrongly," like triplets plus 16ths, or inaccurately, like "triplets but a bit faster," until you get the feel for it, and once you do, try to totally ignore the drum and focus on the mega-beat, however slow it is.